# I want to stop pythoncom working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyhook, pythoncom

I was writing a code about keylogging by pyHook. The following codes are example:

```
import pythoncom as pc, pyHook as ph

def KeyboardHook(event):
    print chr(event.Ascii)
    return True

hm = ph.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = KeyboardHook
hm.HookKeyboard()
pc.PumpMessages()
```

I want to stop pythoncom's PumpMessages method for a while later (for example five seconds). But I couldn't find any answer to it.

I use: Windows 7, Python2.7

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use `pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages` which is **not** blocking.

```
import pythoncom as pc, pyHook as ph
import time

def KeyboardHook(event):
    print chr(event.Ascii)
    return True

hm = ph.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = KeyboardHook
hm.HookKeyboard()

while time.clock() < 5:
    pc.PumpWaitingMessages()
```